# XAMPP phpmyadmin Export Error Missing parameter: what; Missing parameter: export_type

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I was trying to export my database, I receive the following error:

`export.php: Missing parameter: what (FAQ 2.8)`
`export.php: Missing parameter: export_type (FAQ 2.8)`

> 2.8I get “Missing parameters” errors, what can I do?
> Here are a few points to check:
> -In config.inc.php, try to leave the $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] directive empty. See also 4.7 Authentication window is displayed more than once, why?.
> -Maybe you have a broken PHP installation or you need to upgrade your Zend Optimizer. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31134.
> -If you are using Hardened PHP with the ini directive varfilter.max_request_variables set to the default (200) or another low value, you could get this error if your table has a high number of columns. Adjust this setting accordingly. (Thanks to Klaus Dorninger for the hint).
> -In the php.ini directive arg_separator.input, a value of “;” will cause this error. Replace it with “&;”.
> -If you are using Suhosin, you might want to increase request limits.
> -The directory specified in the php.ini directive session.save_path does not exist or is read-only (this can be caused by bug in the PHP installer).<

I looked FAQ suggested link by phpmyadmin above and restart but it does help.